#  How to get data column value on click button inside data grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

How can we get the column value on button click event inside a data grid control,
In the Grid there are five column ,fifth column is button control and first column is some ID value ,
i am using

```
Int32 paperID = Convert.ToInt32(((System.Data.DataRowView)(DataGrid_MarksSummary.SelectedItem)).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
```

here paperID is always coming 0,
how to get this id value on clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your button's click event handler in your code, you can traverse the visual tree in this handler and find the underlying row and the data that you actually need:

```
private void ColumnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Visual visual = (Visual)sender;
        while ((visual = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(visual) as Visual) != null)
        {
            if (!(visual is DataGridRow)) continue;

            var row = (DataGridRow)visual;
            object item = row.Item; //your bound object
            break;
        }
    }
```

in this case 'item' variable holds the actual databound object inside of the DataGridRow. You can cast this to the object type you actually use as the data grid's source and afterwards you get the PaperID that you want from this.